# Effectively querying the database in bulk

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a php page that takes 2.8 seconds to render. The page contains a script that reads a txt file via `file()` line by line (~5000 lines) via a `foreach` loop. This works perfectly and allows me to wrap each line in a `<div>`. This all looks something like this.

```
$text_file = 'path/to/my/text/file.txt';
$lines = file($text_file);
$output = '';
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
  $output .= '<div id="'.$line_num.'" class="line">'.htmlspecialchars($line).'</div>'."\n";
}
echo $output;
```

The problem is I need to query **if a line number is in the database and if it is give it an extra class** `highlight`. This is what is making the page render so slowly. Each line (~5000) is querying the database within the loop. This looks something like this.

```
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
  // codeigniter is being used here
  $line_exists = $this->line_model->lookup_line($line_num);
  // $line_exists checks the database if the $line_num exists it will return true / false
  if($line_exists){          
    $lines_output .= '<div id="'.$line_num.'" class="line highlight">'.htmlspecialchars($line).'</div>'."\n";
  }else{
    $lines_output .= '<div id="'.$line_num.'" class="line">'.htmlspecialchars($line).'</div>'."\n";
  }
}
```

**My question is**: Is there a more efficient / faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what that function checks in the database but one idea to speed things up might be to get the line numbers in database BEFORE the foreach loop. Get all the line numbers in an array, inside the loop just check if the line number is in the array , if it is then use the highlight otherwise the normal case. This way you only query the database once instead of ~5k times.

Comment: This makes sense, I just face-palmed. Thanks `lookup_line checks the database if the $line_num exists it will return true / false`

Comment: @ThomasReggi if the check is as simple as that then you can simply have a range in the query based on the number of lines in the file. `" .. WHERE line_nunber >= 0 AND line_number < ".count($lines)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$text_file = 'path/to/my/text/file.txt';
$lines = file($text_file);

$lineNumbers = array_keys($lines);


$sql = "SELECT id FROM table where lineNumber IN( '".implode("','",$lineNumbers)."' )";
//exicute this line get id in array format, lets say $availableLines varialbe 
//$availableLines

foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
  // codeigniter is being used here
//compare if current line number exits in $availableLines variable
  if(in_array($line_num,$availableLines)){          
    $lines_output .= '<div id="'.$line_num.'" class="line highlight">'.htmlspecialchars($line).'</div>'."\n";
  }else{
    $lines_output .= '<div id="'.$line_num.'" class="line">'.htmlspecialchars($line).'</div>'."\n";
  }
}
```